# Hiding BottomAppBar in UWP(Windows 10)

Tags: c#, uwp, appbar

I am trying to hide my BottomAppBar which is for administrator only in my application.

I want the BottomAppBar to be hidden once I launched it and only to appear when I make a right-click on my mouse.

For now, when I launch my application, the app bar is visible in a minimized mode, like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umkJC.jpg)

I hope to hide it completely, so that users are not aware that there is a setting page/bottomAppBar.

And here's my code:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar Background="{StaticResource CitiKioskBackgroundBrush}"
            IsOpen="False"
            IsSticky="False">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <AppBarButton Name="SettingAppBarButton"
                          Click="SettingAppBarButton_Click"
                          Icon="Setting"
                          Label="Settings" 
                          Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: Consider the Visibility property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the visibility of the bottom app bar to `Collapsed` and then in the `loaded event` of your page write logic to identify the admin user and set the visibility to `Visible`..so you can do something like this ..

**XAML**

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="appBarName" <!-- Added Name -->
            Visibility="Collapsed" <!-- Changed default Visibility -->
            Background="{StaticResource CitiKioskBackgroundBrush}"
            IsOpen="False"
            IsSticky="False"
            Visibility="Collapsed">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <AppBarButton Name="SettingAppBarButton"
                          Click="SettingAppBarButton_Click"
                          Icon="Setting"
                          Label="Settings" 
                          Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

**C#** (Code behind)

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if(admin)//your logic here to identify admin user
     appBarName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

You can add the following code to any event handler that you want for example a button click or RightTapped event..

> Updated Code for toggling visibility

```
bool toggle=false;
//Code for toggling your app bar visibility 
private void UserControl_RightTapped(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    if(toggle)
    {
       appBarName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
       toggle=false;
    }else{
       appBarName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
       toggle=true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi! The setting of the visibility of the bottom app bar to Collapsed really helped me alot! Thanks!

Comment: However, if I want the admin to just perform a right click event on application to open appbar, what should i write for the if statement?

Comment: I have managed to show the appBar, but how problems with hiding it again, I have post it below. It would be great if it can be solved.

Comment: For hiding the app bar again you can simply write `appBarName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;` to hide it in your event.. Also I would recommend you not to add content in the answer section. Rather please add edits to your question..

Comment: I have also added additional code for showing and hiding your app bar.

Comment: I have tried the codes added, I think it is impossible to write the same method twice for different events...

Comment: First of all, don't blindly copy paste the code I am posting,try to understand and ask if you need help .. secondly if you want to toggle you can simply use a boolean variable and use the same event for doing different work .. (updated my answer with this change under **Updated Code for toggling visibility**)